# Can I authenticate with both WooCommerce consumer key and JWT?

Tags: rest-api, authentication

I want to authenticate against *both*:

- the WooCommerce consumer key, for system queries *and*
- JSON Web Tokens (JWT), for user queries

I have installed [JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/). But after activating the plugin, previously working queries (that use the WooCommerce consumer key for authentication) fail with:

```
{'code': 'jwt_auth_bad_auth_header',
 'data': {'status': 403},
 'message': 'Authorization header malformed.'}
```

How can I configure Wordpress / the JWT plugin so that they succeed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes this is possible by structuring your requests appropriately.

For system requests use OAuth 1.0 (consumer key as before), but encode it to include the OAuth credentials *in the URL* not in the headers. Having the OAuth credentials in the `Authorisation` header triggers the JWT error.

```
GET https://DOMAIN/wp-json/wc/v1/subscriptions
* Authorization: `OAuth 1.0`
  * Consumer key: FILLED IN
  * Consumer secret: FILLED IN
  * Other fields: blank
* Headers: blank
* Body: blank
```

To request a token (for a user-based query), you don't use authorization, you include the user credentials in the body:

```
POST https://DOMAIN/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token
* Authorization: `No Auth`
* Headers: blank
* Body: `form-data`
  * key: username, value: test
  * key: password, value: test
```

Once you have the token, you can add it to the `Authentication` header per JWT requirements.

To test these queries, it's easiest to use a dedicated tool like [httpie](https://httpie.org) or [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com).

**Reference:** https://github.com/Tmeister/wp-api-jwt-auth/issues/87

Comment: To do this, you may change `queryStringAuth` to true in the REST API client req. It is disabled by default in official clients https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api-js-lib

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same issue. Jwt Authentication for wp api and woocommerce api not working along with in [ionic3](http://jquerytraining.com) and woocommerce.
I have figured out the issue and done the following

Go to -> `plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/includes/class-jwt-auth.php`

search for the function define_public_hooks() and comment last two lines

```
private function define_public_hooks()
{
    $plugin_public = new Jwt_Auth_Public($this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version());
    $this->loader->add_action('rest_api_init', $plugin_public, 'add_api_routes');
    $this->loader->add_filter('rest_api_init', $plugin_public, 'add_cors_support');
    //$this->loader->add_filter('determine_current_user', $plugin_public, 'determine_current_user', 10);
    //$this->loader->add_filter( 'rest_pre_dispatch', $plugin_public, 'rest_pre_dispatch', 10, 2 );
}
```

Thanks, enjoy.

Comment: As soon as the JWT plugin gets an update this change will be overwritten. This is not a good solution.

Comment: You are right. the changes will be overwritten. Have you other way?

Comment: @JoydebChouhdhury You can use `remove_filter`