# How can I authenticate user credentials against a Wordpress instance?

Tags: users, rest-api, authentication

I am running a second web application in addition to Wordpress/WooCommerce. When users log into the second application, I'd like to authenticate them against the WP instance. I am using the REST API for data queries, but that only allows authentication with a consumer key. The API doesn't provide endpoints for user authentication.

Given a username and password, how can I authenticate against a Wordpress/WooCommerce instance? (In other words, from outside the instance.)

Comment: Have you looked at the wp_authenticate hook? https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_authenticate

Comment: @LPH I assume that is only useful within a running instance? I'm looking to authenticate from outside the instance / against the instance (I've update question to clarify)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) plugin offers a user authentication mechanism. You will need to:

- install and configure the plugin
- make user authentication requests against the new token endpoint

  - optionally use the token to make further queries on behalf of users
  - [continue using OAuth 1.0 for WP/WC REST queries](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/283874)

**References:**

- https://jwt.io/introduction/
- [Using JWT to authenticate a user with an external system?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203686)
- [JWT authentication with WP - Approach](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/204612)